# Capistrano, Passenger and Nginx - How do they work together?

Tags: nginx, capistrano, passenger

I'm currently using Capistrano, Passenger and Nginx with my Rails application, but still, I'm confused on how it all works together.

Here's what I know so far:

**Nginx** is a web server that responds to requests, like Apache but more lightweight.

**Capistrano** is used for deploying web application, it uploads the application code and runs a series of scripts and migrates the database.

**Passenger** is somehow a mystery box to me. I know it spawns ruby processes to handle requests, but isn't this a responsibility of the web server? I've read parts of the Passenger documentation but it still doesn't make much sense. I can see it says it makes deployment a breeze, but isn't this what Capistrano does?

Can anyone give a better explanation? Thanks a lot!